# C Change Value in Union

Tags: c

Let us say I have an union like this:

```
typedef union
{
    int integer;
    char* string;
    double decimal;

} Value;
```

When I initialize it, I write this:

```
Value v = { 12 };
```

But it gives me an error when I want to change the value like this:

```
v = { 14 };
```

Why?

Comment: A union in C Language is a way to define a variable that can be integer or string or ... After you initialize it you are declaring also which type of variable it is since now on..

Answer (score 1):

because { ... } is a initializer list in this case. You can't re-initalize a variable. Try

```
v.integer = 14;
```

instead.